# Where should i propose tags?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to propose some tags for SQA.

parallel, testng, mbunit, dependent tests

Is this the correct place to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are created by the authors who write the questions. If those subjects are not being discussed, you don't "propose" that the tags be created.

If you feel that a question is missing tags, you can add the tags yourself (if you have sufficient reputation), or flag the question to have the tag added.

Answer (score 2):

During the public beta it requires 150 rep to create a tag, and 200 rep to retag a question.

If you have questions that pertain to tags that do not exist, and do not have enough rep to create them yourself, you have two options:

1. Create the post, and put down what tags you'd like it to have. Chances are someone will edit them in for you.
2. Hold off on creating that post until you have acquired the rep. You can get up to 200 rep in a day (more with accepted answers and bounties) so it shouldn't take too long to get that much rep.